# Tools for modeling and simulation of sotware architectures

Tags: architecture, simulation, software-design

My background is in electronic and control systems engineering, where simulation tools for physical systems are very common. In my current professional incarnation I am developing the software architecture for an embedded system that is quite complex.

I understand enough of UML to use it, but I really miss the ability to simulate the system. That is, see how it handles some use cases, have an estimate of processing time and memory used for each one, tryout error scenarios, etc.

Also, this particular project specifications are not final yet and a simulation would be helpful to do an impact analysis as the specifications evolve.

Other than writing the actual software, or writing an abstraction in high-level languages like Python or Java, what tools exist for modeling and simulating a embedded software systems ? Do they support a collaborative design process ?

Answer (score 0):

I found something very interesting that can be helpful to you in the aspect of

> what tools exist for modeling and simulating software systems

the [Design pattern modeling language](http://crpit.com/confpapers/CRPITV10Mapelsden.pdf) is a notation supporting the specification of design pattern solutions and their instantiation into UML design models. DPML provides a set of modelling constructs allowing design pattern solutions to be modelled and reused.

Also [Visual Language for Design Pattern Modeling and Instantiation](http://www.irma-international.org/viewtitle/8150/) and related to it [MaramaDPTool](https://wiki.auckland.ac.nz/display/csidst/MaramaDPTool), which can help you for modelling and instantiating design patterns into UML designs using the Design Pattern Modelling Language (DPML)

- Cheers

Comment: Going through the first paper, it is not clear to me why DPML specific to embedded systems. Nonetheless, the concept is interesting and it is in the direction of what I was looking for. When I have time, I will try out the tool